How to transfer founds to multiple Stripe Connect Accounts before receiving them?
Stripe Connect is a service for marketplaces where each seller has an account. The buyer makes 1 transfer to Stripe, which then transfers a portion of those funds to the sellers' accounts.
There are 2 ways to define such a payment:
First: We define the amount required from the customer, how much of the cash will be received by the seller and to which seller they will go.
Important:

the definition is generated before the buyer makes the payment.
the definition can contain maximum 1 seller.

Second: We define the amount required from the customer + a list of sellers with the amounts they will receive.
Important:

the list of sellers is sent after Stripe receives funds from the buyer.
the definition can contain multiple sellers.

In the first case, there is 1 operation and everything happens on Stripe's side.
In the second case, there are 2 operations that are triggered on our side (defining payments + triggering cash transfers to sellers). And here is where the problem arises: the fact that we have the cash and it's transferred to the sellers' accounts next means that we have access to it. That's a problem from a country regulations perspective.
We have to send the transfers list to Stripe before it receives the payment or don't have access to that money before they are transferred to sellers' accounts.
Have any of you encountered such a problem? Have you solved it in any way?
Do you have any ideas on how to get around this and still use Stripe?

As I understand it what you're describing isn't possible with Stripe today.  In order to transfer funds to a connected account you need to have those funds in your platform's available balance, which means you have access to those funds.  There's no way to preemptively mark funds as inaccessible to you and have them sent to a connected account immediately without you having any access to them.
Beyond that, the closest thing to what you're describing is separate charges and transfers, but it doesn't sound like that would fit all of your requirements.
The other thing you might want to explore are direct charges, where the funds land directly on the connected account instead of your platform, but that approach only works for a single connected account, not multiple.
